# How much mercury is contained in sea salt?

Tags: food-safety, salt

Eating fish means eating mercury in meaningful quanties. The EFSA advocates for that reason against eating tuna every day.

If I buy sea salt, does it also contain mercury? Is so how much? Is it a meaningful quantity such as tuna?

Comment: Did you do any [research](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/353/169) into this question by any chance? Could you share what you found? Thanks, and welcome to the site. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the answer seems to be no, it does not contain a meaningful quantity. Refer first to [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/56700/7632) in *Seasoned Advice*.

Although not peer reviewed, [this article](http://www.spexcertiprep.com/knowledge-base/files/AppNote_GourmetSalts.pdf) appears to be a credible source and it's the only documented direct test for mercury in sea salts that I've seen. Refer to Table 3 (Hg is mercury).

[image]

Comment: I've been looking into this, and I also haven't managed to find another article about quantities of mercury in salt, aside from the one you cited. Their methodology is sound, I can see no apparent conflict of interest as they produce analytical standards (nothing health related) and as someone who's business is in analytics, they should know what they're doing.

Comment: [PDF of the study from archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301071240/http://www.spexcertiprep.com/knowledge-base/files/AppNote_GourmetSalts.pdf).